# Magento2: Multiple image upload in Admin Form

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, multiple-file-upload

I am not using the UI component.

And I want to convert the below code in Form.php

```
<fieldset>
    ...
    <field name="imageUploaderExample" formElement="imageUploader">
        <settings>
            <notice translate="true">Some notice.</notice>
            <label translate="true">Image Uploader Example</label>
            <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <imageUploader>
                <settings>
                    <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="string" name="url">path/to/save</param>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                </settings>
            </imageUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Please suggest.

I need to add multiple uploads in Magento Admin Form not in the UI component.

Answer (score 0):

Magento support available when you use with UI Component

```
<field name="restorent_images">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">geolocation</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image Of Restorent</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type=""string"">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name=""elementTmpl"" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <!-- <item name="isMultipleFiles" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="ranosys_giolocation/index/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```